# How can i use computed propery get value from the store in another one?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i wrote a computed to get a value from the store and here it is code

```
computed: {
      language: function () {
        return this.$store.state.user.language
      }
```

when i use this computed in another one to load data from json file in array like that

```
levels: function () {
         return require('@/assets/languages/' + this.language + '/DataFiles/levels.json')
      }
```

i get an error [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module "@/assets/languages""

although if i write the second computed without parameter it is worked like that

```
levels: function () {
         return require('@/assets/languages/' + 'Spanish' + '/DataFiles/levels.json')
      }
```

how can i solve this problem ?